# Spring Boot Logging with any Log Framework throws a Nullpionterexception

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, logback, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project which throws a Nullpionterexception when trying to Log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.ihc.phr.status.web.StatusController.getStatus(StatusController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Line 26

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
log.debug("I'm Broke!");
```

Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building resource-status 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ phr-status ---
[INFO] org.ppt.phr:phr-status:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.54:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.ppt.ourCompany:ourCompany-util:jar:13.12.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.ppt.service:ourCompany-gds-service:jar:13.12.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.ppt.gds:gdsClientEJB:jar:2.14.73:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.bea:wlthint3client:jar:10.3.3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.ppt.ourCompany:ourCompany-crypto:jar:0.0.5:compile
[INFO]    \- com.ppt:common-ppt:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.270 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-26T14:29:54-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I'm missing something here. I tried to make sure that all derivative dependencies of log4j or other logging frameworks are manually excluded in Maven. But I might be missing something in the current logging config causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I overlooked the declaration of the log attribute. It wasn't initialized properly thus causing the problem.

```
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusController.class);
```